# A regular expression for splitting where the delimited is contained in angle brackets

Tags: java, regex

Consider

```
<_2017-05-15 type="Double">-1.920992100000000E+05</_2017-05-15>
```

How can I treat `<...>` as a delimiter when attempting to split this string (in order that I can pull out the number `-1.920992100000000E+05`?

I tried `<.*>` (and even `\\<.*\\>`) but that is a match for the whole string.

For what it's worth, I'm using Java.

Comment: what is the expected output ?

Comment: did you mean a regex like this [`>(.*?)<\/`](https://regex101.com/r/F4QM3D/1)

Comment: Absolutely! I found the answer from the duplicate. I used `<.*?>` Thank you very much @WiktorStibizew